# How to enable just-in-time debugging with VC# Express

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I need to enable just-in-time debugging on computer having only VC# Express Edition (cannot install full Visual Studio there). Consider C# Console application with the following code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

When I run such application (without C# debugger attached), I have the following message: **ConsoleApplication1 hast stopped working**. The only option is **Close program**. Trying to solve the problem, I installed Debugging Tools for Windows on this computer. Now **ConsoleApplication1 hast stopped working** message has two options: **Debug** and **Close program**. After pressing Debug I have the following message:

**Visual Studio Just-In-Time Debugger.
An unhandled Microsoft .NET Framework exception occurred in ConsoleApplication1.exe [2156]. Just-In-Time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In-Time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.
Check the documentation index for 'Just-in-time debugging, errors' for more information.**

Debugger is still not available. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug registry key has the following information:

```
Debugger  "C:\Windows\system32\vsjitdebugger.exe" -p %ld -e %ld
```

vsjitdebugger.exe exists in system32. What else can I do to enable just-in-time debugging? I need to open .NET debugger, when C# application, running outside C# debugger, crashes with unhandled exception.

Comment: Can't you try the 'normal' windbg as you have installed the Debugging tools? Location of windbg stated here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: How much of the plumbing is put in place for the Express edition is hard to guess at, I wouldn't get my hopes up.  Just make your own just-in-time debugging dialog.  Use MessageBox.Show().  When you see it attach the debugger.